# Deep Copy UIImage with ARC

Tags: ios, uigraphicscontext

I have one UIImage which I want to deep copy to another (so that I may add it to an NSMUtableArray of images)

I cannot get it to deep copy, I have looked at zones and such but this no luck.

This is what I have trieD:

```
_incrementalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIImage *imgcpy = [[UIImage allocWithZone:[_incrementalImage zone]];
[stack addObject:imgcpy];
```

Basically I need a copy of incrementalImage onto stack that won't change if _incrementalImage or currentImageContext changes.

Comment: Does the answer to this question help? (I think a `CGImageRelease()` is missing, but anyway): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867980/how-do-i-make-an-exact-copy-of-a-uiimage-returned-from-a-uiimagepickercontroller

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making deep copy of UIImage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002040/making-deep-copy-of-uiimage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage"];
UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image1.CGImage];
```