# Rotating a CGImage

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage, cgimage

I have a UIImage that I'm getting from a UIImagePickerController. When I receive the image from the `- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info` method I put it straight into a UIImageView for preview and give the user the option to either save or discard the image.

[image: The preview screen]

When the user selects the save option the application get the png data for the image and saves it to it's documents directory. But what happens under one of the 2 possible device orientations (landscape only) is that the image is saved upside down (more specifically, rotated 180 degrees from what it should be). So when I load the image in the gallery it appears upside down.

(See the bottom left image in the gallery)

[image: See the bottom left image]

I have worked this out to be that the raw image data in the UIImage from the UIImagePickerController is not rotated, rather, the orientation is stored as a property on the object and only applied when displaying. So I'm trying to rotate the CGImage associated with the UIImage using some code I found online. But it appears to have absolutely no affect on the image. The code I'm using follows:

```
- (void)rotateImage:(UIImage*)image byRadians:(CGFloat)rads
{   
    // calculate the size of the rotated view's containing box for our drawing space 
    UIView *rotatedViewBox = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width, image.size.height)];
    CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rads);
    rotatedViewBox.transform = t;
    CGSize rotatedSize = rotatedViewBox.frame.size;

    // Create the bitmap context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize);
    CGContextRef bitmap = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Move the origin to the middle of the image you want to rotate and scale around the center. 
    CGContextTranslateCTM(bitmap, rotatedSize.width/2, rotatedSize.height/2); 

    // Rotate the image context
    CGContextRotateCTM(bitmap, rads);

    // Now, draw the rotated/scaled image into the context
    CGContextScaleCTM(bitmap, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(image.size.width / 2, image.size.height / 2, image.size.width, image.size.height), [image CGImage]);

    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationDown];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

I would like to know why this code isn't working, since every piece of code I find online to do this image rotation appears to not work.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
-(UIImage*) rotate:(UIImage*) src andOrientation:(UIImageOrientation)orientation
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(src.size);

    CGContextRef context=(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

    if (orientation == UIImageOrientationRight) {
        CGContextRotateCTM (context, 90/180*M_PI) ;
    } else if (orientation == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
        CGContextRotateCTM (context, -90/180*M_PI);
    } else if (orientation == UIImageOrientationDown) {
        // NOTHING
    } else if (orientation == UIImageOrientationUp) {
        CGContextRotateCTM (context, 90/180*M_PI);
    }

    [src drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    UIImage *img=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;

}
```

use this one .. it works perfect ! Just make sure you use this function when you are picking images from UIImagePicker:

example:

```
UIImage *image;
image = [self rotate:image andOrientation:image.imageOrientation];
```

Make sure to use this function in place where you pick photos from documents directory.

Comment: nice answer... the only thing I would change is that "`return img;`" gets called before "`[img release];`" (which means the release call never actually hits).  Also, this assumes the person is not using ARC.

Comment: Does one know why rotation is necessary?

Comment: @testing https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/orientation

Answer (score 10):

### Rotate and Mirror UIImage CGImage Backing Data - Swift

I recently wanted to correct a `UIImage` backed by a `CGImage` to match the desired orientation rather than rely on APIs to respect the UIImageOrientation parameter.

```
func createMatchingBackingDataWithImage(imageRef: CGImage?, orienation: UIImageOrientation) -> CGImage?
{
    var orientedImage: CGImage?
    
    if let imageRef = imageRef {
        let originalWidth = imageRef.width
        let originalHeight = imageRef.height
        let bitsPerComponent = imageRef.bitsPerComponent
        
        let bitmapInfo = imageRef.bitmapInfo
        
        guard let colorSpace = imageRef.colorSpace else {
            return nil
        }
        
        var degreesToRotate: Double
        var swapWidthHeight: Bool
        var mirrored: Bool
        switch orienation {
        case .up:
            degreesToRotate = 0.0
            swapWidthHeight = false
            mirrored = false
            break
        case .upMirrored:
            degreesToRotate = 0.0
            swapWidthHeight = false
            mirrored = true
            break
        case .right:
            degreesToRotate = 90.0
            swapWidthHeight = true
            mirrored = false
            break
        case .rightMirrored:
            degreesToRotate = 90.0
            swapWidthHeight = true
            mirrored = true
            break
        case .down:
            degreesToRotate = 180.0
            swapWidthHeight = false
            mirrored = false
            break
        case .downMirrored:
            degreesToRotate = 180.0
            swapWidthHeight = false
            mirrored = true
            break
        case .left:
            degreesToRotate = -90.0
            swapWidthHeight = true
            mirrored = false
            break
        case .leftMirrored:
            degreesToRotate = -90.0
            swapWidthHeight = true
            mirrored = true
            break
        }
        let radians = degreesToRotate * Double.pi / 180.0
        
        var width: Int
        var height: Int
        if swapWidthHeight {
            width = originalHeight
            height = originalWidth
        } else {
            width = originalWidth
            height = originalHeight
        }
        
        let contextRef = CGContext(data: nil, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: 0, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue)
        contextRef?.translateBy(x: CGFloat(width) / 2.0, y: CGFloat(height) / 2.0)
        if mirrored {
            contextRef?.scaleBy(x: -1.0, y: 1.0)
        }
        contextRef?.rotate(by: CGFloat(radians))
        if swapWidthHeight {
            contextRef?.translateBy(x: -CGFloat(height) / 2.0, y: -CGFloat(width) / 2.0)
        } else {
            contextRef?.translateBy(x: -CGFloat(width) / 2.0, y: -CGFloat(height) / 2.0)
        }
        contextRef?.draw(imageRef, in: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: CGFloat(originalWidth), height: CGFloat(originalHeight)))
        orientedImage = contextRef?.makeImage()
    }
    
    return orientedImage
}
```

Comment: " you're rotating the context (and its coordinate system) then drawing the image into it." For that reason, they could have called a context an easel, right? Wonder why they didn't. It's easier to understand what an "easel" is (after all, most people have used one) than to understand what a "context" is.

Comment: What is the difference between your solution and the one from [Dream.In.Code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10548409/426227)? You are taking more cases into account (e.g. mirrored images). But what else? Some angles seem to be different and also the used methods (`CGContextRotateCTM `  vs. `rotate`). Also you are doing a `translateBy`, which the other solution doesn't take into account ...

Comment: Also what is the difference to this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/schickling/b5d86cb070130f80bb40)?

Comment: The difference is... relying on UIKit to be there. This is exclusively using CoreGraphics which is available on macOS and iOS.

Answer (score 5):

The **Swift 3** version for the [Cameron Lowell Palmer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27730890/6282606):

```
func createMatchingBackingDataWithImage(imageRef: CGImage?, orienation: UIImageOrientation) -> CGImage? {
    var orientedImage: CGImage?

    if let imageRef = imageRef {
        let originalWidth = imageRef.width
        let originalHeight = imageRef.height
        let bitsPerComponent = imageRef.bitsPerComponent
        let bytesPerRow = imageRef.bytesPerRow

        let colorSpace = imageRef.colorSpace
        let bitmapInfo = imageRef.bitmapInfo

        var degreesToRotate: Double
        var swapWidthHeight: Bool
        var mirrored: Bool
        switch orienation {
        case .up:
            degreesToRotate = 0.0
            swapWidthHeight = false
            mirrored = false
            break
        case .upMirrored:
            degreesToRotate = 0.0
            swapWidthHeight = false
            mirrored = true
            break
        case .right:
            degreesToRotate = 90.0
            swapWidthHeight = true
            mirrored = false
            break
        case .rightMirrored:
            degreesToRotate = 90.0
            swapWidthHeight = true
            mirrored = true
            break
        case .down:
            degreesToRotate = 180.0
            swapWidthHeight = false
            mirrored = false
            break
        case .downMirrored:
            degreesToRotate = 180.0
            swapWidthHeight = false
            mirrored = true
            break
        case .left:
            degreesToRotate = -90.0
            swapWidthHeight = true
            mirrored = false
            break
        case .leftMirrored:
            degreesToRotate = -90.0
            swapWidthHeight = true
            mirrored = true
            break
        }
        let radians = degreesToRotate * Double.pi / 180

        var width: Int
        var height: Int
        if swapWidthHeight {
            width = originalHeight
            height = originalWidth
        } else {
            width = originalWidth
            height = originalHeight
        }

        if let contextRef = CGContext(data: nil, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace!, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue) {

            contextRef.translateBy(x: CGFloat(width) / 2.0, y: CGFloat(height) / 2.0)
            if mirrored {
                contextRef.scaleBy(x: -1.0, y: 1.0)
            }
            contextRef.rotate(by: CGFloat(radians))
            if swapWidthHeight {
                contextRef.translateBy(x: -CGFloat(height) / 2.0, y: -CGFloat(width) / 2.0)
            } else {
                contextRef.translateBy(x: -CGFloat(width) / 2.0, y: -CGFloat(height) / 2.0)
            }
            contextRef.draw(imageRef, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: originalWidth, height: originalHeight))

            orientedImage = contextRef.makeImage()
        }
    }

    return orientedImage
}
```

Usage:

```
let newCgImage = createMatchingBackingDataWithImage(imageRef: cgImageRef, orienation: .left)
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem with all these answers is that they have UIKit dependencies. I'm working on a SwiftUI Universal app targeting both iOS and macOS. The [Cameron Lowell Palmer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544887/rotating-a-cgimage/27730890#27730890) works with a few modifications :

1. The bytesPerRow calculation needs to be done *after* the swap of height and width, or the CGImageContext whines about incorrect bytesPerRow
2. change the UIImageOrientation to CGImagePropertyOrientation, and swap the signs for left & right rotations

Here is my version, suitable for both iOS and macOS:

```
extension CGImage {
func rotating(to orientation: CGImagePropertyOrientation) -> CGImage? {
    var orientedImage: CGImage?

    let originalWidth = self.width
    let originalHeight = self.height
    let bitsPerComponent = self.bitsPerComponent
    let bitmapInfo = self.bitmapInfo

    guard let colorSpace = self.colorSpace else {
        return nil
    }

    var degreesToRotate: Double
    var swapWidthHeight: Bool
    var mirrored: Bool

    switch orientation {
    case .up:
        degreesToRotate = 0.0
        swapWidthHeight = false
        mirrored = false
        break
    case .upMirrored:
        degreesToRotate = 0.0
        swapWidthHeight = false
        mirrored = true
        break
    case .right:
        degreesToRotate = -90.0
        swapWidthHeight = true
        mirrored = false
        break
    case .rightMirrored:
        degreesToRotate = -90.0
        swapWidthHeight = true
        mirrored = true
        break
    case .down:
        degreesToRotate = 180.0
        swapWidthHeight = false
        mirrored = false
        break
    case .downMirrored:
        degreesToRotate = 180.0
        swapWidthHeight = false
        mirrored = true
        break
    case .left:
        degreesToRotate = 90.0
        swapWidthHeight = true
        mirrored = false
        break
    case .leftMirrored:
        degreesToRotate = 90.0
        swapWidthHeight = true
        mirrored = true
        break
    }

    let radians = degreesToRotate * Double.pi / 180.0

    var width: Int
    var height: Int

    if swapWidthHeight {
        width = originalHeight
        height = originalWidth
    } else {
        width = originalWidth
        height = originalHeight
    }

    let bytesPerRow = (width * bitsPerPixel) / 8

    let contextRef = CGContext(data: nil, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue)

    contextRef?.translateBy(x: CGFloat(width) / 2.0, y: CGFloat(height) / 2.0)

    if mirrored {
        contextRef?.scaleBy(x: -1.0, y: 1.0)
    }

    contextRef?.rotate(by: CGFloat(radians))

    if swapWidthHeight {
        contextRef?.translateBy(x: -CGFloat(height) / 2.0, y: -CGFloat(width) / 2.0)
    } else {
        contextRef?.translateBy(x: -CGFloat(width) / 2.0, y: -CGFloat(height) / 2.0)
    }

    contextRef?.draw(self, in: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: CGFloat(originalWidth), height: CGFloat(originalHeight)))

    orientedImage = contextRef?.makeImage()

    return orientedImage
}
```

}

Comment: Actually, the bytesPerRow calculation is unnecessary. If the data: item is nil, then bytesPerRow can be zero and it will be automatically calculated

Answer (score 3):

I got your problem.You have to translate back the context using     `CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -rotatedSize.width/2, -rotatedSize.height/2);` as well as set origin of rect in drawing to rotatedViewBox.frame.origin.x,rotatedViewBox.frame.origin.y.
use this code.

```
UIView *rotatedViewBox = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width, image.size.height)];
CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.3);
rotatedViewBox.transform = t;
CGSize rotatedSize = rotatedViewBox.frame.size;



UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, rotatedSize.width/2, rotatedSize.height/2);
CGContextRotateCTM (context, 0.3);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -rotatedSize.width/2, -rotatedSize.height/2);




CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(-rotatedViewBox.frame.origin.x, -rotatedViewBox.frame.origin.y, image.size.width, image.size.height), [image CGImage]);


UIImage *nn = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

NSLog(@"size is %f, %f",nn.size.width,nn.size.height);
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(nn, nil,nil,nil);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is just refactoring of previous answer.

```
func correctImageOrientation(cgImage: CGImage?, orienation: UIImage.Orientation) -> CGImage? {
    guard let cgImage = cgImage else { return nil }
    var orientedImage: CGImage?

    let originalWidth = cgImage.width
    let originalHeight = cgImage.height
    let bitsPerComponent = cgImage.bitsPerComponent
    let bytesPerRow = cgImage.bytesPerRow
    let bitmapInfo = cgImage.bitmapInfo

    guard let colorSpace = cgImage.colorSpace else { return nil }

    let degreesToRotate = orienation.getDegree()
    let mirrored = orienation.isMirror()

    var width = originalWidth
    var height = originalHeight

    let radians = degreesToRotate * Double.pi / 180.0
    let swapWidthHeight = Int(degreesToRotate / 90) % 2 != 0

    if swapWidthHeight {
        swap(&width, &height)
    }

    let context = CGContext(data: nil, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue)

    context?.translateBy(x: CGFloat(width) / 2.0, y: CGFloat(height) / 2.0)
    if mirrored {
        context?.scaleBy(x: -1.0, y: 1.0)
    }
    context?.rotate(by: CGFloat(radians))
    if swapWidthHeight {
        swap(&width, &height)
    }
    context?.translateBy(x: -CGFloat(width) / 2.0, y: -CGFloat(height) / 2.0)

    context?.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: CGFloat(originalWidth), height: CGFloat(originalHeight)))
    orientedImage = context?.makeImage()

    return orientedImage
}

extension UIImage.Orientation {
    func getDegree() -> Double {
        switch self {
        case .up, .upMirrored:
            return 0.0
        case .right, .rightMirrored:
            return 90.0
        case .down, .downMirrored:
            return 180.0
        case .left, .leftMirrored:
            return -90.0
        default:
            return 0
        }
    }

    func isMirror() -> Bool {
        switch self {
        case .up, .right, .down, .left:
            return false
        case .leftMirrored, .upMirrored, .downMirrored, .rightMirrored:
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
}
```