# Is it possible to rotate a CGImage without redrawing it so it can be used as the CALayer content property

Tags: ios, iphone, core-graphics, quartz-core

Is it possible to rotate a `CGImage` data without redrawing the image? I would like to impact the orientation of an image in such way that when set as a `CALayer` `content` property, the `CGImage` rotation is taken into account.

Comment: Why not simply rotate the layer instead?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544887/rotating-a-cgimage

Comment: @DarkDust it's to use for export in an AVExportSession on an AVSynchronizedLayer , it is said to avoid transforming layers.