# AVCapturePhoto rotated 90 counterclockwise after calling `cgImageRepresentation()!.takeUnretainedValue()`

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I'm working on an app that take square pictures on iOS with `AVFoundation`. When I save the image with the following statements in `photoOutput(_:, didFinishProcessingPhoto:, error:)`, the image saved in my album have correct direction.

```
func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
    PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { status in
        guard status == .authorized else { return }

        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            let creationRequest = PHAssetCreationRequest.forAsset()
            creationRequest.addResource(with: .photo, data: photo.fileDataRepresentation()!, options: nil)
        }, completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

However, when I replace the code with the following in order to save the `CGImage` object, I found the image saved in my album was rotated by 90 counterclockwise.

```
func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
    let image = photo.cgImageRepresentation()!.takeUnretainedValue()
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage(cgImage: image), nil, nil, nil)
}
```

Here's my configuration of my photo capture pipeline.

```
private func initializeCapturePipeline() {
    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    captureSession?.sessionPreset = .photo
    captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back)
    videoInput = try! AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice!)
    imageOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
    captureSession?.addInput(videoInput!)
    captureSession?.addOutput(imageOutput!)
    imageOutput?.connection(with: .video)?.videoOrientation = .portrait
    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession!)
    previewLayer?.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
    videoContainerView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)
    captureSession?.startRunning()
}
```

I wonder what is causing the problem? How could I fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that the underlying image data is the same in both cases, and that the difference in the display is due to the lack of metadata in the `photo.cgImageRepresentation()`. The Photos app is aware of the image metadata and automatically applies the rotation and/or mirroring necessary based on the value of the "Orientation" property in the image metadata.

Using the `PHPhotoLibrary` function results in a copy of the image with embedded metadata. As described in [CGImagePropertyOrientation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/imageio/cgimagepropertyorientation), iOS is saving the object with the orientation `.right`. However, the `CGImage` created directly from the `AVCapturePhoto` object does not contain the associated metadata.

There are a couple of potential fixes (these have not been tested but should help to find a working solution):

1. Create the `UIImage` using the orientation obtained from the photo metadata.

```
func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
    let image = photo.cgImageRepresentation()!.takeUnretainedValue()
    let orientation = CGImageProperyOrientation(rawValue: photo.metadata["Orientation"] as! UInt32)
    var uiImage: UIImage!
    if orientation == .right {
        uiImage = UIImage(cgImage: image, scale: 1.0, orientation: .right)
    } else {
        uiImage = UIImage(cgImage: image)
    }
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(uiImage, nil, nil, nil)
}
```

2. Save the `CGImage` with metadata using a `CGImageDestination` and the `CGImageDestinationAddImageAndMetadata` function from the [Image I/O framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/imageio).
3. Depending on the precise use case, it may be necessary to explicitly rotate the image data. Examples of how to do this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544887/rotating-a-cgimage).